# Why Error Code :1064 in MySQL? Can you help and explain to me?

Tags: mysql

this is my DDL

```
USE test_1;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS sales;

CREATE TABLE sales (

  ‘key’       varchar(6) NOT NULL,

  ‘ts’        timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

  ‘product’   integer,

  ‘completed’ boolean,

  ‘price’     float,

  PRIMARY KEY (‘key’)

);

INSERT INTO test_1.sales 
VALUES

 ('sale_1', ‘2019:11:08 00:00’, 0, 'TRUE', 1.1),

 ('sale_2', ‘2019:11:08 01:00’, 0, 'FALSE', 1.2),

 ('sale_3', ‘2019:11:08 01:00’, 0, 'TRUE', 1.3),

 ('sale_4', ‘2019:11:08 01:00’, 1, 'FALSE', 1.4),

 ('sale_5', ‘2019:11:08 02:00’, 1, 'TRUE', 1.5),

 ('sale_6', ‘2019:11:08 02:00’, 1, 'TRUE', 1.5);

SELECT * FROM sales;
```

Comment: It looks like you're using the wrong type of quotes around your column names. Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html

Comment: ya, I checked, thank you so much - have a good day